# Making a GUI operate from the Windows command line

Tags: c++, c, parameters, command-line-arguments

I'm working on software that operates through a GUI and I was tasked with writing functions to make it run through the Windows Command Line and I'm not sure how to code it through `int argc` and `char** argv`. Could someone please provide me with a small example. I am new to C so this a little over my head.

It should go something like "Parameter A" calls "Function 1" then the next parameter can be "Parameter B" which calls "Function 2" or "Parameter C" which calls "Function 3."

Parameter_1   (Paramter_2 | Parameter_3)

Comment: Are you asking how to make just a command-line interface, or how to have both command-line interface and a GUI interface for the same program?

Comment: What do you mean when you say a parameter calls a function? Are you talking about types that allow function callbacks like function pointers and functors or do you mean something else?

Comment: Command Line and GUI for the same program. The program needs to be able to be called from the Windows command line. And it is in C. And to answer greatwolf's comment. If "parameter B" is entered it will execute "Function 2" which might be 2+2=4 but if "parameter C" is entered it will execute "function 3" which might be 3+3=6 for example if that makes sense.

Comment: @user2517789 Any program can be invoked from the command-line whether it's a console app or a GUI app.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, I recommend creating two different apps, one for command line and one for GUI. The only difference between the two is that one is built with code that handles command line input and the other would have code to use a GUI interface. The two would have in common the rest of the code that is interface agnostic, meaning it will work regardless of the interface.

For the second question, there's plenty of tutorials out there for command line parsing, [like this one](http://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-command-line-parameter-parsing) I spent ten seconds to find.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to iterate through the parameters passed to `main()` and call functions based on any matches that you find. A basic `main()` function looks like the following

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

`argc` is the number of arguments and `argv` is an array of `char` pointers to C style strings containing individual arguments. The C based example below should get you started.

<sub>(Although you tagged your question as both C and C++ you only mention C in your question so that is the language I chose for the example.)</sub>

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void execA()
{
    // ... do something 
}

void execB()
{
    // ... do something 
}

void execC()
{
    // ... do something 
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if(0 == _stricmp("paramaterA", argv[i]))
        {
            execA();
        }
        else if(0 == _stricmp("paramaterB", argv[i]))
        {
            execB();
        }
        else if(0 == _stricmp("paramaterC", argv[i]))
        {
            execC();
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unknown parameter: %s", argv[i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you. That seems to be working. How would I code it if I wanted to include a parameter for uploading a boot and app file after the initial parameters are passed in?

Comment: Add a flag and a variable or two that gets set from the argument handler (e.g. replace `execC();` with `flag = true; flagArgs = argv[i]`' and check the flag and call the appropriate function after the `for` loop. There are also plenty of answers on SO that already provide explanations of this.